# mulitple JSON feeds in an array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pull 5 separate JSON feeds and have it looping where every individual has a nested getJSON.

```
var feedList [feed1,feed2,feed3,feed4,feed5];

for (feed in feedList) {

  var index = 0;
   $.getJSON(feedList[feed], function(data) {
        $.each(data.items, function(i, obj) {
               $('li').append(obj.title + '=' + index + '<br>');
            });
        index++;
    }       

}
```

For some reason in firebug it shows that I go through the for in loop then pull the feed successfully then completely bypass the anything inside the .getJSON loop. It doesn't go back into .getJSON loop until all the feeds are pulled. This messes up the order of the items being pulled and also the order is random every time I refresh the page. (e.g. feed2 is listed first then feed4 next)

I've also tried doing a regular for loop instead of a for in loop but it still changes nothing.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order would be random because `$.getJSON` is an asynchronous request for a file. Put simply each request will take some time to complete, and your function (with the `each` call) will only be called for each request once each request completes respectively.

The problem arises in the fact that you cannot control which requests will return in which order. Since the all are requested at the same time.

---

You could get the feeds in order by waiting until each request completes before trying the next request:

```
var feedList [feed1,feed2,feed3,feed4,feed5];
var index = 0;

function getFeed(index) {
    $.getJSON(feedList[index], function(data) {
        $.each(data.items, function(i, obj) {
            $('li').append(obj.title + '=' + index + '<br>');
        });
        if (index < feedList.length - 1)
            getFeed(++index);
    });
}

getFeed(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Send the next request on success of the previous one by using a recursive function

```
function getFeed(feed){
    $.getJSON(feed, function(data) {
        $.each(data.items, function(i, obj) {
               $('li').append(obj.title + '=' + index + '<br>');
            });
        if(feedList.length > index + 1)
            getFeed(feedList[++index]);
    }       
}
// start
getFeed(feedList[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a regular loop, combined with self executing anonymous functions. You may need to explicitly disable asynchronicity for ajax, though.

```
for ( var i = 0, l = feedList.length; i<l; ++i ) {
    (function() {
        // $.getJSON code
    })();
}
```

Actually the inner function is probably useless. You can disable asynchronicity with

```
$.ajaxSetup( { "async": false } );
```

Comment: This is not a good recommendation. Looping with with synchronous ajax is bad.

Comment: Agreed. I'd go with your way instead.